# Mapbox set fill-color dynamically

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using the Mapbox library and I have this function that processes a response of type JSON, but I want the color of every single feature to be dynamic based on a property of the feature itself:

```js
function doSome(data) {
    
    map.addSource('hrd-src', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': data
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'hrd-polygons',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'hrd-src',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': '#088',
            'fill-opacity': 0.8
        }
    });

    // Set filter to first hour of the day
    // 0 = mezzanotte del giorno corrente (0-23)
    filterBy(0);

    document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        var hour = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
        filterBy(hour);
    });
}
```

Is it possible to set a dynamic value for the `fill-color` property?

Comment: See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#expressions using expressions you can set the fill color dynamically based on the feature properties.

Comment: Thanks!  I used this:

paint': {
            'fill-color' : {
                "property": "color",
                "stops": [
                  [0, 'white'],
                   [1, 'yellow'],
                  [2, 'orange'],
                  [3, 'red'],
                  [4, 'violet']
              ]
            },
            'fill-opacity' : 0.5
        }

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a complete article about this:
https://blog.mapbox.com/data-driven-styling-for-fill-layers-in-mapbox-gl-js-80bb5292af4e

If you use categorical attribute,
then you have to use *'type': 'categorical'*:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#other-function